# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/crashlytics/android/core/CrashlyticsCore;

Tags: android, google-fabric, android-multidex

I have added Fabric to my app. But in some device i revice error bellow, when I open app. I have already added Multidex in Application.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.mitapp.dist_android, PID: 15828
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/crashlytics/android/core/CrashlyticsCore;
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:29)
        at ru.mitapp.dist_android.App.onCreate(App.java:97)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4793)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:152)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ru.mitapp.dist_android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ru.mitapp.dist_android-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        ... 13 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 14 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

In my gradle:
(stack ask to write something so sl;dkfsa;dkfa;sdknfasdfasdf;snd;flnasldfnlsdfnlksajdnflkasjdnflkasjdnflksajdnflkasjdnflsajdnfklasdhfksadjfkhsadfksahdflksahdflkjsadhflkasjhdflksajdhfkljsadhflksajdhflaksjdhflasjkdhfljksda) Excuse me for this.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'realm-android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.mitapp.dist_android"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 20
        versionName "1.0.20"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.github.IntruderShanky:Sectioned-RecyclerView:2.1.1'

    //rxJava/rxAndroid/retrofit
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

    //picasso/downloaderPicasso
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'

    //ButterKnife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    //section RecyclerView
    compile 'com.github.IntruderShanky:Sectioned-RecyclerView:2.1.1'

    //navigationBottom
    compile 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'

    //Surface scan
    //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

    //mask for enter phone number
    implementation 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'

    //cirler photo
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    //maskEditTask
    compile 'com.github.pinball83:masked-edittext:1.0.3'

    //bage
    compile 'q.rorbin:badgeview:1.1.0'

    //calendar
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'

    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'

    compile 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:v0.0.4'

    compile 'com.github.rampo.updatechecker:library:2.1.8'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And in my Application:

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MultiDex.install(this);

    context = getApplicationContext();


    Realm.init(this);
    final RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder()
            .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
            .schemaVersion(9)
            .migration(new TasksMigration())
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);

    Fabric.with(context, new Crashlytics());

    And some retofit code...}
```

It work when I install to device in debug, but if i download it from playMarket it brokes down

Comment: It didn't help me

Comment: please provide your build.gradle where you set your dependencies and your Application class.

Comment: gradle and Application done

Comment: Everything seems correct except   MultiDex.install(this); on create and attachBaseContext? I don't think you need to call this method twice. Maybe it causes the problem? Try removing it from onCreate()

Comment: is instant run enabled and tried to run app in below android M devices?

Comment: I'm not good at English, can't understand this question. Could you reask?

Comment: As I see, it brokes down only one Lollipop